# Gnome Install Error (1)

Tags: 12.04, installation, dependencies

I'm trying to install Gnome on my Ubuntu 12.04 P.Pangolin and getting the following errors:

```
    root@***:~# sudo apt-get install gnome-core gnome-session-fallback
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gnome-core is already the newest version.
gnome-session-fallback is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Setting up bluez (4.98-2ubuntu7) ...
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript bluetooth, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing bluez (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-bluetooth:
 gnome-bluetooth depends on bluez (>= 4.36); however:
  Package bluez is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing gnome-bluetooth (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-shell:
 gnome-shell depends on gnome-bluetooth (>= 3.0.0); however:
  Package gnome-bluetooth is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing gnome-shell (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-user-share:
 gnome-user-share depends on gnome-bluetooth; however:
  Package gnome-bluetooth is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing gnome-user-share (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-core:
 gnome-core depends on gNo apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                                                  No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                 No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                    No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                  nome-bluetooth (>= 3.0); however:
  Package gnome-bluetooth is not configured yet.
 gnome-core depends on gnome-shell (>= 3.0); however:
  Package gnome-shell is not configured yet.
 gnome-core depends on gnome-user-share (>= 3.0); however:
  Package gnome-user-share is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing gnome-core (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 bluez
 gnome-bluetooth
 gnome-shell
 gnome-user-share
 gnome-core
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Syslog:

```
Oct  5 16:04:17 ks34900 bluetoothd[5176]: Bluetooth daemon 4.98
Oct  5 16:04:17 ks34900 bluetoothd[5176]: Starting SDP server
Oct  5 16:04:17 ks34900 bluetoothd[5176]: opening L2CAP socket: Address family not supported by protocol
Oct  5 16:04:17 ks34900 bluetoothd[5176]: Server initialization failed
Oct  5 16:04:17 ks34900 bluetoothd[5176]: Failed to init alert plugin
Oct  5 16:04:17 ks34900 bluetoothd[5176]: Failed to init time plugin
Oct  5 16:04:17 ks34900 bluetoothd[5176]: Failed to init proximity plugin
Oct  5 16:04:17 ks34900 bluetoothd[5176]: Failed to open control socket: Address family not supported by protocol (97)
Oct  5 16:04:17 ks34900 bluetoothd[5176]: Can't init bnep module
Oct  5 16:04:17 ks34900 bluetoothd[5176]: Failed to init network plugin
Oct  5 16:04:17 ks34900 bluetoothd[5176]: Unable to start SCO server socket
Oct  5 16:04:17 ks34900 bluetoothd[5176]: Failed to init audio plugin
Oct  5 16:04:17 ks34900 bluetoothd[5176]: Failed to init gatt_example plugin
Oct  5 16:04:17 ks34900 bluetoothd[5176]: Can't open HCI socket: Address family not supported by protocol (97)
Oct  5 16:04:17 ks34900 bluetoothd[5176]: adapter_ops_setup failed
Oct  5 16:04:17 ks34900 kernel: init: bluetooth main process (5176) terminated with status 1
Oct  5 16:04:17 ks34900 kernel: init: bluetooth main process ended, respawning
Oct  5 16:04:17 ks34900 bluez: Stopping uarts
Oct  5 16:04:17 ks34900 bluez: Stopping rfcomm
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get update` before install?

Comment: @ Evandro Silva yes i did..no errors..

Comment: updated the syslog in the Q

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, this should work well, but **you have to be careful** and you'll have to revert back the changes when you are done. This will only fix your installation problem, not your problem with `bluetoothd`.

```
sudo mv /usr/sbin/bluetoothd /usr/sbin/bluetoothd-please-rename-me-when-you-are-done
sudo ln -s /bin/true /usr/sbin/bluetoothd
```

Then install:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-core gnome-session-fallback
```

This step is optional, update:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If your system doesn't have any other problem, then the installation should complete well. When the update is complete, revert back the poor `bluetoothd`:

```
sudo rm /usr/sbin/bluetoothd
sudo mv /usr/sbin/bluetoothd-please-rename-me-when-you-are-done /usr/sbin/bluetoothd
```

Now the installation problem should be fixed, but you still have a problem with `bluetoothd`, probably this one:

```
Oct  5 16:04:17 ks34900 bluetoothd[5176]: opening L2CAP socket: Address family not supported by protocol
```

[Open another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) and good luck!

Comment: Vote up if it worked!!!